Is it possible to bypass the administrator prompt when invoking mrt via the command line?
I want to set up a job that automatically and quietly runs a full scan using the malicious software removal tool periodically.
I've found that the command to do so is mrt /Q /F, but this prompts for administrator approval. The problem with that is twofold: An application pseudo-randomly asking for administrator privileges is suspicious at best, and I want this to work even when I am away from my machine.
Is there a way to bypass the need for this?
(Extra context: To achieve the effect of running it periodically, I'm using WSL to create a cron job of 0 0 * * 6 cmd.exe /C mrt /Q /F)

try scheduling it to run in task scheduler, checking the box for "run with highest privileges".
